# Wordpress (page builder) swap divs on collapse to mobile

Tags: wordpress

I am implementd page builder plugin wordpress, i need to swap two columns in mobile resolution .
Now my div structure is 
image-text
text-image
image-text
text-image

But,in mobile resolution i need to display as
image
text
image
text
one by one.

how to add the css for this structure.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Blow is my code

Comment: can you check this and help me out? http://floretmedia.net/temp/nlf/

Comment: on which section you are referring ?

Comment: from 4th section in mobile resolution, i need to display as first image next text

Answer (score 0):

Try this css.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #pg-30-3{
        #pgc-30-3-0{
            order: 2;
        }
        #pgc-30-3-1{
            order: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

otherwise add class to  your div `left-side-cont` and `right-side-cont`

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

        .left-side-cont{
            order: 2;
        }
        .right-side-cont{
            order: 1;
        }

}
```

Comment: you need to do for css other images also.